# Flattened Spiral Permutation Index

Tags: code-golf, sequence, permutations, matrix

### Context

Consider square matrices with `n` columns and rows containing the first `n^2` (i.e. `n` squared) positive integers, where `n` is odd. The elements of the matrices are arranged such that the integers `1` through `n^2` are placed sequentially in a counterclockwise spiral starting at the center and initially moving to the left. Call these matrices `M(n)`

For `n=1` this simply gives the one element matrix `M(1)=[[1]]`.

`M(3)` is the matrix

```
9 8 7
2 1 6
3 4 5
```

`M(5)` is the matrix

```
25 24 23 22 21
10  9  8  7 20
11  2  1  6 19
12  3  4  5 18
13 14 15 16 17
```

and `M(7)` is the matrix

```
49 48 47 46 45 44 43
26 25 24 23 22 21 42
27 10  9  8  7 20 41
28 11  2  1  6 19 40
29 12  3  4  5 18 39
30 13 14 15 16 17 38
31 32 33 34 35 36 37
```

Now consider flattening this matrix into a list/array by concatenating its rows starting from the top and moving down. Call these lists `L(n)`. `L(3)`, `L(5)` and `L(7)` are represented below, with their elements delimited by spaces.

```
9 8 7 2 1 6 3 4 5     (n=3)
25 24 23 22 21 10 9 8 7 20 11 2 1 6 19 12 3 4 5 18 13 14 15 16 17    (n=5)  
49 48 47 46 45 44 43 26 25 24 23 22 21 42 27 10 9 8 7 20 41 28 11 2 1 6 19 40 29 12 3 4 5 18 39 30 13 14 15 16 17 38 31 32 33 34 35 36 37    (n=7)
```

We can find the index `i(n)` of `L(n)` in a lexicographically sorted list of permutations of `L(n)`. In Jelly, the `Œ¿` atom gives this index for the list it acts on.

### Challenge

Your challenge is to take an positive odd integer `n` as input and output the index `i(n)`.

The first few values are

```
n  i(n)
-------
1  1
3  362299
5  15511208759089364438087641
7  608281864033718930841258106553056047013696596030153750700912081
```

Note that `i(n)` ~= `(n^2)!`. This is not on OEIS.

This is code golf per language, so achieve this in the fewest bytes possible.

[Sandbox post](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14716/75553).

Answer (score 3):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), <s>21</s> 19 bytes

```
-;,N$ṁx"RFḣNṙ-+\ỤŒ¿
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ASgA1/9qZWxsef//LTssTiThuYF4IlJG4bijTuG5mS0rXOG7pMWSwr////8z)

Based on the method from a J article on [volutes](http://www.jsoftware.com/papers/play132.htm).

### Explanation

```
-;,N$ṁx"RFḣNṙ-+\ỤŒ¿  Main link. Input: integer n
-;                   Prepend -1. [-1, n]
  ,N$                Pair with its negated value. [[-1, n], [1, -n]]
     ṁ               Mold it to length n.
        R            Range. [1, 2, ..., n]
      x"             Vectorized copy each value that many times.
         F           Flatten
           N         Negate n
          ḣ          Head. Select all but the last n values.
            ṙ-       Rotate left by -1 (right by 1).
              +\     Cumulative sum.
                Ụ    Grade up.
                 Œ¿  Permutation index.
```

Answer (score 2):

## J, <s>48</s> 38 Bytes

-10 bytes thanks to @miles !

```
[:A.@/:_1+/\@|.(2#1+i.)#&}:+:$_1,],1,-
```

Old:

```
3 :'A.,(,~|.@(>:@i.@#+{:)@{.)@|:@|.^:(+:<:y),.1'
```

Note that the result is 0-indexed, so `i(1) = 0` and `i(5) = 15511208759089364438087640`

#### Explanation (old):

```
3 :'                                           ' | Explicit verb definition
                                            ,.1  | Make 1 into a 2d array
                                     (+:<:y)     | 4*n, where y = 2*n + 1
                                   ^:            | Repeat 4*n times
                              |:@|.              | Clockwise rotation
       (                    )@                   | Monadic Hook:
             (          )@{.                     | To the first row, apply...
                      {:                         | The last and largest item
                     +                           | Added to...
              >:@i.@#                            | The list 1, 2, ..., n; where n is the row length
          |.@                                    | Reverse
        ,~                                       | Append to the top of the array
      ,                                          | Ravel
    A.                                           | Permutation index
```

Making the spiral could be quicker, but the orientation would get messed up.

I don't know how J is optimizing this, but it only takes `0.000414` seconds to calculate for `n=7` (on a fresh J console session).

Comment: Maybe J does something similar to how I made Jelly do it ([code](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly/commit/c61ff293c2098af856b13a9c86fda20e30b280af#diff-282e2d1a9fff46656251b082622c7ea4R662))?

Comment: I golfed your method to 39 bytes ``[:A.@,,.@*0&((,~(#\.+{:)@{.)@|:|.)~2*<:``. I also golfed a version of the method in the [volute article](http://www.jsoftware.com/papers/play132.htm) to 38 bytes ``[:A.@/:_1+/\@|.(2#1+i.)#&}:+:$_1,],1,-``.

Answer (score 1):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), <s>16</s> <s>15</s> 14 bytes

```
lYL!PletY@wXmf
```

Fails for test cases larger than `3` due to both floating-point inaccuracies and memory limitations.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/PyfSRzEgJ7Uk0qE8Ijft/39jAA)

#### Explanation

```
lYL    % Implicit input n. Spiral matrix of that side length
!P     % Transpose, flip vertically. This is needed to match the orientation
       % of columns in the spiral with that of rows in the challenge text
le     % Convert to a row, reading in column-major order (down, then across)
t      % Duplicate
Y@     % All permutations, arranged as rows of a matrix, in lexicographical
       % order
w      % Swap
Xm     % Row membership: gives a column vector containing true / false,
       % where true indicates that the corresponding row in the first input 
       % matches a row from the second output. In this case the second input
       % consists of a single row
f      % Find: gives indices of nonzeros. Implicit display
```

Comment: Does MATL have built-ins for spirals?

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer It may have [one](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/125969/36398)

Comment: Explanation added

Answer (score 1):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 27 bytes

```
ZUðẎṀ+ṚW;⁸µJ
1WÇẎ⁸²¤ḟ$$¿ẎŒ¿
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/z8q9PCGh7v6Hu5s0H64c1a49aPGHYe2enEZhh9uBwqDeJsOLXm4Y76KyqH9QIGjkw7t////vzkA)